# Using ":" in ssh hostname resolves different IP for host?

Tags: networking, ssh, dns

Forgetting to use `-p` instead of the `:` notation for specifying an ssh port to connect to, I ran the command

```
ssh myserver.biz:55555
```

I realized my mistake when an IP that does not belong to my server was apparently resolved.

```
The authenticity of host 'myserver.biz:55555 (not.my.ip.add)' can't be established...
```

Obviously I quickly declined to continue connecting to this machine that is unknown to me.

Any ideas what could be causing this? Connecting properly with the `-p` option resolves the address correctly, but I'm really curious as to what is happening when using `:` in a hostname.

Comment: What OS was this from?

Comment: @Paul Mac OS X 10.12, the client is OpenSSH

Comment: Similar issue: OpenSSH is made by the OpenBSD people, and use skey for otp.  When using scp, using "useracct:skey@site:/path" seems to interpret the first colon as the separator before the path, so the solution is to not use that syntax which is invalid in this case.  I must use "-l useracct:skey" to specify logon name (and then "site:/path", with no @ needed).  (I don't have a convenient OSX system to verify identical behavior there.)

Comment: My magic eight-ball says your Internet provider may be doing [DNS hijacking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNS_hijacking#Manipulation_by_ISPs).

Comment: @Kenster I believe this is definitely it. I have noted that any attempts to resolve an invalid hostname return the same IP. Thanks for the informative link.

Answer (score 1):

OpenSSH is passing the whole hostname to resolve for your system DNS resolver. Valid hostname should not contain colons, but if your DNS responded to your request with valid IP address, SSH tried to connect there. Without the real name you tried it is hard to guess what happened.

Answer (score 0):

With help from @Jakuje and @Kenster, I've determined that my ISP has some form of "[DNS Hijacking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNS_hijacking#Manipulation_by_ISPs)" enabled.

OpenSSH is passing the full hostname argument, with colon, to be resolved. Obviously a hostname containing a colon is not valid, therefore instead of appropriately responding with `NXDOMAIN`, the DNS server responds with what they think is a helpful hint, an IP address to a server that has a webserver on port 80 to show a search page (which they undoubtedly gain ad revenue from).